# Expandable and Collapsable UITableViewCell with Custom Views

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitableview, ios6

Not Getting any Idea on how to solve this ....

Ok. This is my custom `UITableViewCell` with three different **Child Views**. That you can see with different colors.

[image]

Here , **Height** of my second **Child View** is dynamic and be calculated at run time. I am using  `-heightForRowAtIndexPath` to set the height of `UITableViewCell`.

**What I have tried :**

I set the Outlets of Child Views and then in  `-heightForRowAtIndexPath` , I used this Code...

```
middleView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 60.0, 750.0, size);
footerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, size + 60.0, 750.0, 50.0);
```

where, size = Dynamically Calculated Height of Middle View.

**UPDATE :**

I have also tried with static value of size like this ...

```
 middleView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 60.0, 750.0, 350.0);
 footerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 350.0 + 60.0, 750.0, 50.0);
```

But No Luck at All....

Size is calculated by this : `size = (elements * 30) + 50;`

where , elements = Number of elements in the Array.

**Problem :**

Look, at the Screenshot.

**Any Suggestions ?**

Comment: ur code is correct, issue is around calculating the size(Height of Middle View)

Comment: @NAZIK : Just see my UPDATE....

Comment: footerView is the 3rd row of the tableview or is it the footerView of tableview section?

Comment: @NAZIK : No, all the Views are in One Single UITableViewCell.....

Comment: ok, these three are in one cell, how many rows totally there

Comment: @NAZIK : It has nothing to do with "Howmany Rows" btw No of Rows are Dynamic....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25678/discussion-between-nazik-and-vin)

Comment: Your middle view and footer view is inside one cell ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your middle view and footer view frame in following method instead of heightForRowAtIndexPath:

and keep your other method as given by indra Mohan above.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath       *)indexPath
{   
NSString * cellIdentifier = @"TableViewCellIdentifier"  ;
InAppTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

cell.delegate = self;
float size = [self heightForMiddleViewAtIndexPath: indexPath]
cell.middleView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 60.0, 750.0, size);
cell.footerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, size + 60.0, 750.0, 50.0);
return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you have to do two things

1. set proper autoresizingMask to all your child views

   ```
       headerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
   middleView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
   footerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
   ```
2. return proper height from UITableViewDelegate method

   ```
   (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
   return [self heightForMiddleViewAtIndexPath: indexPath] + footerViewHeight + headerViewheight;
   }
   (CGFloat)heightForMiddleViewAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
   \ do some height calculation;
   }
   ```

Comment: It's not working at all. I tried with Static Values (See UPDATE in my Question) also.

Comment: if it is still not working you can overwrite UITableViewCell's layoutSubviews methods and you can update frames of cells subviews in that method.